# syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN, expecting T_FUNCTION oop php

Tags: syntax-error, php

Im receiving an error as stated above. Its referring to my return statement. Any one got any clues on this?! Thankful for all help!
Regards!

```
public function getPosts() {
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");

    $posts = array();
    while($posts = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($posts, new Post($post['id'], $post['created'], $post['author'], $post['title'], $post['body']));      
    }

} 
return $posts;
```

Answer (score 13):

Your return statement should come before the last closing brace.

```
        while($posts = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($posts, new Post($post['id'], $post['created'], $post['author'], $post['title'], $post['body']));      
        }

        return $posts;                                          
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answers. I found the answer just after I posted the question :) a bit to quick on my finger I reckon. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka the potter get scared of unicorn!!! :P

Answer (score 3):

Your `return` statement needs to be inside the function `getPosts()`. Currently it is outside or you have one `}` on the wrong line.